# Mongoose close connection issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

In my node js program, After opening mongo connection I trying to run certain query and finally trying to close connection.

```
group.find({group_name: "music"}, function (doc) {
  // do your stuff
  console.log(doc);
  mongoose.connection.close();
});
```

But while I trying to see mongotop log, after closing the connection, its still show as connected
[image: mongotop log]

Here finananceManagement is the the database, which I tried to connect, If I restart the mongo service it will disapper from the log, help me to resolve this issue

Comment: The `connection.close()` method returns a promise, so it might not close the connection right away.

Comment: If I am not wrong you are saying that promise is not full filled. I also tried await for the mongoose close command. Still it showing in the log